# Exclude information from metrics endpoint

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

The metrics endpoint can respond with a lot of data, especially for `cache.` and `gauge.`. Is there a way to exlude this and only show the [system metrics](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-metrics.html#production-ready-system-metrics)?

I'm asking this because the endpoint is polled by Logstash and it exceeds the maximum number of fields per index.

Comment: Good question (+1) Did you try excluding these two classes like this 
`@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {ServoMetricsAutoConfiguration.class, MetricFilterAutoConfiguration.class})`

Comment: That did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for cache. Add this to one of your configuration classes:

```
@Bean
public CachePublicMetrics emptyCachePublicMetrics() {
    return null;
}
```

Also, in my particular case with Logstash, the problem can be solved by adding a prune filter to the Logstash config:

```
prune {
  blacklist_names => [ "^cache\.", "^gauge\." ]
}
```